# Adding namespaced attribute to django-crispy-form field

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I was trying to add a namespaced attribute (`x-bind:attr`) to a crispy form field but I couldn't find a solution that works. I know that attributes with a dash are handled by using an underscore, I tried to do the same by replacing double underscore with the double colon but it didn't work and no replacement is made.

````
class ChildFormSetHelperUpdate(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_tag = False
        self.include_media = False
        self.layout = Layout(
            Div(Field('model', x_bind__disable="disableInput"), css_class='col-md-6'),
        )
        self.render_required_fields = True```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing the keyword argument in a dictionary, and expanding that into the kwargs for `Field` using the `**` [unpacking operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters):

```py
Field('model', **{"x-bind:disable": "disableInput"})
```

This gets around the fact that you can't use dashes and colons in Python variable names. The attribute will be rendered as:

```html
<input ... x-bind:disable="disableInput">
```